# Re-installing GNURoot Debian on Android Kitkat

Tags: gnuroot

Recently i was using GNURoot Debian to run debian on my android kitkat device. But I had to uninstall it due to some reasons. Now i am installing it again and it is not installing. It says :
Application not installed
I tried several times but in vain.

So i was asking for a solution for it.
And, yeah, i wanna know the reason behind this error.

I remember the same problem happened in Debian noroot while re-installing it. I came to know that it happened due to a bug in Android 4.x. Is this the same kind of bug or an another reason behind this error ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happes when there is folder of previously installed gunroot in /data/data
Try deleting or renaming it before installing..
It may work

Comment: Ohh thanks. It's working now